# Gauge anomaly from conformal dimension?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, gauge-theory, conformal-field-theory, quantum-anomalies, chern-simons-theory

According to ref.1, the Chern-Simons theory $\mathrm{SU}(N)_k$ has a $\mathbb Z_N$ one-form symmetry with anomaly
$$
\eta=\exp\left[-2\pi i \frac{k}{N}\right]\tag{4.12}
$$
which, apparently, can be computed by from the known value of the conformal dimension of the $\mathbb Z_N$-generator, to wit,
$$
\Delta=\frac{(N-1)k}{2N}
$$

How does that come about? How is $\Delta$ related to the 't Hooft anomaly, in general terms? Given an arbitrary CS theory, and a discrete symmetry generated by $a$, how is the anomaly $\eta_a$ related to $\Delta_a$? From the expression above, it so appears that $\eta_a=\exp(4\pi i\Delta_a)$. Is this a general result? Where does it come from?

**Refererences.**

1. Gaiotto, Kapustin, Seiberg, Willett - [*Generalized Global Symmetries*](https://arxiv.org/abs/1412.5148), §4.4.